# Cannot install ubuntu 16.04 : AER: Corrected error received

Tags: 16.04, usb-installation

I have Ubuntu and Linux mint USB flash drive installer. Both are 16.04 (Mint 18) and no matter what I do, it can't finish the installation process without stuck, also I see that my root folder suddenly have no room anymore when I'm waiting for installation to finish.

When I open the installation console there is a lot of repeated error messages: `AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5` 
The computer is DELL INSPIRON Desktop with I think Intel Skylake i5 in it.

While searching I found that AER problem is well known problem and connected with Intel Skylake architecture.

And for now there is only one solution - hide that messages using one of next boot parameters:

```
pci=noaer
pci=nomsi
pcie_aspm=off
pci=nommconf
```

The question is : How to to this with USB installation medium?